# How do you access the built in Compoundjs helper methods from a noeval controller?

Tags: node.js, compoundjs

How do you access the built in Compoundjs helper methods from a noeval controller?

From an eval'd controller the helper functions seem to get loaded automatically and they are just accessible by doing something like this:

```
before('protectFromForgery', function () {
    protectFromForgery('some_secret_key');
});
```

But not sure what the best way is to access them from a non-eval'd controller.

They seem to be located in /compound/node_modules_kontroller/lib/helpers.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. All the built-in helper methods are just attached to the controller context object. (The variable 'c' in the following examples)

So you would do something like this:

```
//Example of noeval controller: app/controllers/car.js:

module.exports = CarController;

// load parent controller
var Essentials = require('./essentials');

function CarController(init) {
    // call parent constructor
    Essentials.call(this, init);

    init.before(function protectFromForgery(c) {
        c.protectFromForgery("some_secret_key");
    }, {only: 'accelerate'});

}

// setup inheritance
require('util').inherits(CarController, Essentials);

CarController.prototype.accelerate = function(c) {
    c.send(++this.speed);
};

CarController.prototype.brake = function(c) {
    c.send(++this.speed);
};
```